# VB 2010 Adding rich text to a richtextbox

Tags: vb.net

Using VB 2010 Express. I have a richtextbox control rtxbxResult and I would like to add text with superscript - I have numbers a, b and c and would like to have a^2 +b^2 = c^2, i.e. 2^2 +3^2 = 4^2 (obviously with 2 superscript). I am getting confused with the richtextbox .Text, .SelectedText, .Rtf and how they work.

I can add text to the control with

```
rtxbxResult.Text &= intA & "^2 " & intB & "^2 = " & intC & "^2" & vbCrLf"
```

I tried using .SelectionCharOffset and .SelectedText but it didn't give me an offset:

```
rtxbxResult.SelectionStart = rtxbxResult.TextLength
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = String.Format("{0,6:#,#}", lngA)
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 1000
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = "3"
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 0
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = " + "
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = String.Format("{0,6:#,#}", lngB)
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = -50
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = "3"
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 0
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = " + "
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = String.Format("{0,6:#,#}", lngC)
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 50
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = "3"
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 0
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = " = "
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = String.Format("{0,6:#,#}", lngD)
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 50
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = "3"
rtxbxResult.SelectionCharOffset = 0
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = " = "
rtxbxResult.SelectedText = String.Format("{0,12:#,#}", lngD3) & vbCrLf
```

All the 3s just print beside the result and not superscript or subscript.
Looking at RTF codes just confused me even more, because they use the .RTF property. If I use the following code:

```
Private Sub btnTestRTF_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTestRTF.Click
    rtxbxResult.Clear()
    rtxbxResult.Rtf = "{\rtf1 This is how to enter VB{\sub net} with net subscripted.\par}"
    rtxbxResult.Rtf &= "{\rtf1 How{\sub about this?}\par}" & ControlChars.Cr
End Sub
```

I get the first line ok, but the second line doesn't show up at all. If I change the 2nd line to .rtf = it overwrites the first line. And if I step through with debug, the text doesn't even appear in the text box until I exit the subroutine, not as each line is executed. I'm not sure what setting the .Rtf property does and how that translates into visible text in the richtextbox. What's the difference between the .Text property and the .Rtf property? How do I add rich text to what's already in the box?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\super` to insert a superscript inside an RTF document, as described here:

- [How to add Sub & superscript in richtextbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a229fc0-cfe4-401d-ad9d-47f63bb60714/how-to-add-sub-superscript-in-richtextbox?forum=winforms)

Relevant parts from the linked article - translated from C#:

```
' Now lets insert \super
selectedRtf = selectedRtf.Insert(selectedRtf.IndexOf(selectedText), "\super")

' Now set the Rtf back to the control
richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = selectedRtf
```